# HTML5 Video On Local Server

Tags: html, centos, html5-video

I have a company training video loaded onto a local server. I'm using HTML5's video playback to view these videos. This server can not access the web, but I have loaded apache and port 8080 is open to all machines on the same network.

The files sit in /var/www/html/Videos/An_Industry_Overview
The html file is test2.htm
The video files sit in the same directory.

My current code is as follows

```
<html>
<body>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <video id="video1" width="720" controls>
    <source src="overview.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="overview.ogv" type="video/ogv">
    <source src="overview.webm" type="video/webm">
  </video>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The player itself loads, and it acts like it's loading the video (loading circle going around and around), but that's all it does. I also tried inserting the full http url and also subbing out the server name with the localhost ip 127.0.0.1 but I get the same results. Why can't I get it to load?

EDIT:
Default .htaccess and httpd.conf files. Added video file types to /etc/mime.types. Tested in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Hmmmm this is odd!  Code looks fine.  Could you also post your apache settings?  Perhaps it's the server configuration that's not letting the server serve the files.

Comment: httpd.conf and .htaccess are all default. I've added the video types to /etc/mime.types and restarted httpd service without any luck.

Comment: Well... your code looks fine.  I'd say also add a height, and test it with these videos from w3schools.com:

http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4
http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.ogg

Comment: Does the video play in firefox if you type in the location of the .mp4 file directly into the URL bar?

Comment: @RobertMcKee Removed my last comment... it does work if I use a direct URL to the mp4 video

Comment: oi vey... discovered that it had to do with case sensitivity in the URL... and the fact that the src= doesn't like relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the case on the src, and change it to a fully qualified URL.